# Debugging in GDB: Is there a way to have inputs automated from a separate file?

Tags: c, gdb

For example, when the user is prompted with an input from a `scanf()`, is there a way to, say, have a text file with inputs that can be read as user inputs instead of having to type in the inputs every time?

I am trying to make a sorted linked list that is being sorted as the user inputs the integer. The way I have it set up is the user selects an option from a menu, and if they pick adding another integer to the list, they input another integer.
I tried making a text file with one integer on every line (first to pick from the menu, and second to pick the number they want in the list) and used `set args inputs.txt`, but it looks like it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use input redirection:

Make a text a file of ordered inputs just as you would type inputs in and execute the file with

./a.out < inputs.txt

Depending if you are on windows or unix machines the syntax could be a little different, if I rememeber Windows vscode used something a little different but its only a google search away.

Edit: found an old file I worked on using Powershell through VsCode, here's how I redirected if your not on Unix.

Get-Content input.txt | ./program < output.txt.

also used:

gcc array.c stats.c

get-content input.txt | ./a.exe

These are old programs so I honestly don't remember the exact contents and functions of these files but I do know this is how I redirected an automated test input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input redirects in the gdb `run` command:

```
$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) run <inputs.txt
```

will run gdb with a binary and then run the program with input redirected from `inputs.txt`